# Tree structure in Symfony's Entity Type

Tags: php, sql, symfony

My table looks like this

```
categories:
- id
- name
- parent
```

In my form you can select multiple categories. I'm using this code for the form builder

```
->add('categories', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:CourseCategory',
            'choice_label' => function(CourseCategory $category) {
                return \AppBundle\Helper::categoryIndent($category) . ' ' . $category->getName();
            },
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er
                        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.parent');
            },
            'choice_attr' => function($category, $key, $index) {
                $attrs = [];

                $attrs['data-id'] = $category->getId();
                $attrs['class']   = 'tree-item';

                if($category->getParent() != null) {
                    $attrs['data-parent'] = $category->getParent()->getId();
                }

                return $attrs;
            }
        ])
```

This doesn't work so far, since the `orderBy` statement is wrong...

How to get a recursive tree structure here?

**Edit**

What I'm trying to achieve looks like this:

```
Category
    Subcategory 1
    Subcategory 2
        Sub-subcategory 1
    Subcategory 3
Category
    Subcategory
```

I do *not* know the depth of trees.

Comment: The ordering and the tree structure as nothing to  do. What are you actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to **display** a nested tree? What is the depth of your tree? Is it limited? Is it known or unknown? Your actual strategy may work for limited depth (to 1) but will be painful for more.

Comment: Edited entry post.

Comment: try to add `'group_by' => 'parent'` to your type options, where parent is the name of the field in your entity.

Comment: Tried to add `group_by`, but it's still not working. Order is completely wrong (It's Category 1, Category 2, Subcategory 1, Subcategory 2, Subsubcategory 1).

Comment: Why are you ordering by `u.parent`? I guess you may want to order by id or by name? Don't you?

Comment: It's not about ordering, it's about getting a tree structure. Ordering by name doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: In your previous comment, you just said, the ordering was wrong. No matter the order is, do you get a nested tree using the `group_by`? Note you can also provide a callback function to `group_by` and define your grouping strategy yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but maybe someone can still profit from my answer.

When displaying tree, you have to order it by "left", below my example:

```
->add('parent', EntityType::class,
                    array(
                        'class'         => Menu::class,
                        'choice_label' => function(Menu $menu) {
                            return TreeHelper::getIndentForTreeElement($menu) . ' ' . $menu->getTitle();
                        },
                        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $em) {
                            return $em->createQueryBuilder('t')->orderBy('t.lft', 'ASC');
                        }
                    )
                )
```

Depth of the tree or parent ids don't matter as long as tree is properly built with right and left values.